# 1D array into a 2D array C++

Tags: c++

Here I have an array of 10. How can I make this into a 2D array of say 2 by 5.

```
double arr1D[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
```

What I want the 2D array to be like:

```
double arr2D[2][5] = {1,2,3,4,5},{6,7,8,9,10};
```

Also how would I do it if I had a pointer to an array. So kinda like this:

```
double arr1D[10];
double*ptr;
ptr = arr1D;
```

Comment: You *could* `std::memcpy(arr2D, arr1D, sizeof(arr2D));` — this does not enforce type safety, but it will work.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "make" and "like."  You could just copy it in a function from a 1D array to a 2D array or wrap it in a class with accesses like a 2D array, Or declare a pointer to a 2D array and assign it with a cast. The latter two don't create a new array but just provide 2D like access to the original. So what is it you wish to do?

Answer (score 0):

Lets take a closer look at how your `arr1D` would look like in memory:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+
```

It's a simple and contiguous chunk of memory.

Now how would that `arr2D` look like in memory? Actually *just the same!*

So the simplest way is just to use e.g. [`std::copy_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n) to copy from one array to the other:

```
double arr1D[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
double arr2D[2][5];

std::copy_n(&arr1D[0], 10, &arr2D[0][0]);
```

---

For the last code snippet, you don't have a "2D array". Instead the pointer variable `ptr` will point to the first element of `arr1D`. You can then use `ptr` almost as you use `arr1D` (the biggest difference is that `sizeof arr1D != sizeof ptr`).